# Cherrypy as windows service. Path not found

Tags: python, windows-services, cherrypy

I've manged to get my (flask) app running with cherrypy as wsgi server like this:

```
from mypyapp import app
import cherrypy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tree.graft(app, "/")
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'log.screen': True,
        'server.socket_port': 8888,
    })
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Now I am trying to install it as a windows service and I run into problems. Here's the code:
    import cherrypy
    from mypyapp import app

```
class PyWebService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    """ Py Web Service """

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        cherrypy.tree.mount(app, "/")

        cherrypy.config.update({
            'global': {
            'engine.autoreload.on': False,
            'log.screen': False,
            'log.error_file': 'c:\\Temp\\error.log',
            'engine.SIGHUP': None,
            'engine.SIGTERM': None,
            'server.socket_port': 8888,
        }
        })

        cherrypy.engine.start()
        cherrypy.engine.block()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        cherrypy.engine.exit()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ConcertWebService)
```

I can install and run the service and the output in the log indicating that it is running without any problems. But when I try to access the server with a browser I get 404

```
404 Not Found

The path '/' was not found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\viktor.forsman\IdeaProjects\cfas\venv\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Users\viktor.forsman\IdeaProjects\cfas\venv\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\viktor.forsman\IdeaProjects\cfas\venv\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cperror.py", line 411, in __call__
   raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/' was not found.")
```

I cannot understand what the differences can be in the configurations. Any ideas are very welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel stupid. In my service module I did:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(app, "/")
```

Change this to:

```
cherrypy.tree.graft(app, "/")
```

And it works.